# Where is the third book in the quest Hitting the books?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have

> killed the Caller

and in that room I've found two of the three books on the two pillars in the side rooms.
Where is the third book? The central pillar was empty. Can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it just over the body of the Caller herself. Maybe she had it on her. Or maybe some action made ejected it from the pillar.

Comment: Turns out it *is* on the central pillar. Reloaded an earlier save and everything was fine. Maybe the corpse was on top of the book before. not sure.

Comment: No books are on the corpse.

Comment: Every time I have done this quest the resulting fight, with fireballs and Atronach explosions galore have meant that the books are blasted randomly everywhere. Keep looking in corners etc. Though it is not impossible that they are blasted through the floor (great engine after all)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, I had exactly this issue.

By deselecting every other active quest, the third book then had a marker over it on re-entering the Ritual room. It was almost the same colour as the floor and would have been impossible to spot without this quest marker appearing just over it.

I'm pretty sure that marker wasn't over the third book when I'd been in the room previously (when I had multiple active quests).

Answer (score 2):

The quest highlights the books with a giant arrow. I found two on a pedestal, and the third one knocked over by the fighting. Since they get thrown around so easily by all the magic, it is possible it was knocked through a wall.

Try to grab the books before the fighting starts to make sure.

Comment: I can't find any of the books. I'm in the Fellglow Keep? Are they in the dungeon further down?

Comment: they are in the ceremonial room where the final battle is.

Comment: there was definitely no arrow pointing to the third book in my case.

Comment: Whether it's possible to grab the book before the fighting starts or not might depend on your dialog choices. Considering to leave the prisoner there gives you fee-roam without the Caller being aggro until you touch the first book...

Answer (score 2):

you can use clairvoyance to locate the last book if it fell through the floor or a wall.

Comment: This is what I would do, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but then had an auto save file save over the battle that took place. If this happens to you, and you can't restart from just before the battle, try pressing start, opening up your mission menu and pressing X over "Find three books". In my case, the arrow hovered directly over where the book was in the room, which was knocked over by the fighting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at the end of the battle. If you select the journal and set the quest to track it will lead you to the book - my missing book was on the floor in a dark corner after the fight.